# jQuery Mobile .ui-page min-height is large

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cordova

i build html\css app using phonegap
the jury mobile give me the div:

```
<div data-role="page" data-url="/Users/tzahianidgar/Desktop/My Project/NaughtyLittleTurtles/Code/NLT/www/MainScreenIndex.html" tabindex="0" class="ui-page ui-page-theme-a ui-page-active" style="min-height: 736px;">
```

and the min-height is too large in emulator i see black line in bottom
like this:

[image: the black line]

if i change the min-height: 736px in the css file it's work but after refresh it's back to min-height: 736px

this what happened after i add:
    `.ui-page-active {min-height:100vh; -webkit-background-size: cover; -moz-background-size: cover;  -o-background-size: cover; background-size:` cover;}

the image:
[image: the code after i change]

Comment: where do you change this value?

Comment: in developer tools in google chrome

Comment: dum lol ! change it in your css/html file not in the developer tools that value is temporary

Comment: i know but after i change it in the css file i think the query mobile fix it to min-height: 736px again

Comment: from what i can see the window of the developer tool is larger than 736px

Comment: I assembled it so we could see the black line

Comment: what do you want to do with the black line?

Comment: remove it i need to make this app for mobile and if we have the black line i over the resolution of screen on phone

Answer (score 0):

try `background-size:cover`:

```
.ui-page-active {
min-height:100vh;
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
 -o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
}
```

https://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Comment: add this to your div with the background image to cover the black area

Answer (score 0):

the fix is simple i just margin the Body in zero

```
 margin: 0;
```